# Get multiple <p> elements with Jquery and add them to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to extract multiple `<p></p>` elements and append them to a single div. I can only seem to get the first paragraph. Any idea?

I'm using this code:

```
$("#result").append($wikiDOM.find('p').html());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `.html()`

```
$("#result").append($wikiDOM.find('p')); //Remove .html()
```

When you use `.html()` it will give you the HTML of first element only, not all of the paragraphs in the jQuery set. But note that using `append` on an element that's already in the document will *move* it from its old location to its new one (whereas appending the HTML of an element just copies it).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to get the `html()` from the selected elements - you can append them directly:

```
$("#result").append($wikiDOM.find('p'));
```